# What should I have on my PC after overwriting Windows?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, software-recommendation

Alright so, my Windows crashed, I did not have a system restore, an OS CD, or any backups, I figured, I wanted to learn more of CLI and such, get an actual feel on Linux Operating System, so, after hours of research and finding a USB, I managed to install Ubuntu 64 bit and overwrite my whole Windows OS using a 16 GB USB. So, it is installed and everything, my questions are...

- What should I install, driver wise? Adobe Flash, DirectX, e.t.c ?
- Will I still be able to play games as I did with my Windows, like, I am assuming yes, because the actual graphics driver / card, and I/O connectors (audio, and all that stuff) is actually on the motherboard of this laptop, but I want to be sure.
- What are some programs that is a must have, or useful such as gdebi (which I have already), or perhaps a tar extractor so I will not have to do something like tar -zxvf or something of the sort. Last but not least, which virus scanner should I use on here?

Answer (score 3):

> What should I install, driver wise?

Ideally nothing. Ubuntu will have picked all the open source drivers it can find for you. You can install a 3rd party driver though, open up dash and search for "additional drivers". It will list all the not open source drivers available.

> Adobe Flash, DirectX, e.t.c ?

- DX is Microsoft. We use OpenGL (and you will already have that installed).
- Flash is nowadays an issue within the browsers. The HTML5 browsers should not require it.

> Will I still be able to play games as I did with my Windows, like, I am assuming yes, because the actual graphics driver / card, and I/O connectors (audio, and all that stuff) is actually on the motherboard of this laptop, but I want to be sure.

No. Anything related to DX does not work on Ubuntu.  There are games for Linux based on OpenGL that work natively, like Planescape: Torment, Baldur's Gate, Neverwinter Nights. And a few more.  [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) (an attempt to be able to run windows software on linux) is a method playing games in Linux.

There is also [Steam for Linux](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=&sort_by=_ASC&os=linux&page=1) (about 25*219, roughly 5400 games). In my opinion very good. You could still use a dual boot to play your windows games.

> Last but not least, which virus scanner should I use on here?

I have lived without one for all my Linux experience. So can you.

> What are some programs that is a must have

That highly depends on you but lucky for you it is all free. So use Ubuntu software center to have a browse. Besides what is installed by default I use SMPlayer (for video) and Shutter (for taking screenshots).

> tar -zxvf

Ignore anything on the web that is not offered through the official channels (stick to Ubuntu software center and if really needed PPA's from Launchpad).  If you do go outside them investigate the owner of that download. Don't be a Windows user on Linux ;)

Comment: Many -if not all - modern 3D games won' t work with the virtualized graphics card. A VM is not a solution for games unless you can passthrough the graphics. AFAIK, Virtualbox doesn't do it.

Comment: My experience is that the games I've cared about work well enough in Wine, usually most readily via PlayOnLinux (makes it easy to try different Wine versions, and practical to use different versions for each game, if needed).

Comment: Hmmm  Xen 4+ can do that though

Answer (score 0):

Most times, when you install Ubuntu, it installs the correct drivers for your hardware automatically, along with Libre Office (an office suite analogous to Microsoft Office before it went to the cloud).  If the system boots to the Ubuntu Desktop, you've got usable graphics drivers (though perhaps not optimal; you'll need to know what graphics hardware you have to check that); if it connects to your wi-fi, you've got working wi-fi drivers, etc.

Flash is optional, but can be installed in the default Firefox browser with the `pepper-flash-plugin` package.  Java similarly; you should already have Open JDK, but if you want, you can replace it with actual Java with a package available from duinsoft.  Direct-X is a Windows extension, and doesn't exist as such in Ubuntu; most things that would have used Direct-X will use Open GL instead.

These, however, are all GUI tools; for learning CLI, they're really unnecessary.  For that, you just need a copy (ideally printed, but at the least on another device like a phone or tablet) of the Ubuntu manual.  Start by learning how to use `man`, it'll get you information on how to use anything else.

Comment: I have a huge problem going on as well. I made a seperate post on here about it, however, this Ubuntu keeps freezing, nothing works. I have tried everything with ctrl alt and f1, nothing works, except for a force restart via, power button. Also, in Other Software, it says cdrom main restricted... Im tired of force booting this pc every like 10 minutes.

Comment: @JarWolf Please edit that other question and add relevant info regarding your hardware. It may require additional different and/or proprietary drivers, especially for the graphics, the above notwithstanding. Or it could be defective...

Comment: How would I add my hardware and specs using Linux. I am used to dxdiag then exporting the txt file or pasting it all from the txt file haha.

Comment: Got it. I did lspci -vv